# Laravel 5.x and Columns name with blank space

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In my blade template I have a problem with a DB column with a blank space.

`{{ $data->first name }}` doesn't work.

Is there any alternative solution?

P.s. I can't modify my column name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to access the column:

```
{{ $data->{'first name'} }}
```

or

```
{{ $data['first name'] }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i tried {{ $data->{'first name'} }} and {{ $data->['first name'] }}, i was so close to the solution :D